# Why is $\mathbb{Q}(x)\ncong \mathbb Q(x,y)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ here is the fraction field of $\mathbb Q[x]$. If there exists such an isomorphism $\theta:\mathbb Q(x,y) \rightarrow \mathbb Q (x)$, then it can be shown that
\begin{align*}
x &= q(\theta(x),\theta(y))\\
\theta(y) &= g(x)\\
\theta(x) &= f(x)\\
\end{align*}
where $q,f,g$ are rational functions. Then we have
\begin{align*}
y &= g(q(x,y))\\
x &= f(q(x,y))
\end{align*}
I think there is a contradiction between these two lines, but I can't explain why.

#### Update:

I think I can explain why, using the derivative operator.From the last two lines we can infer:
\begin{align}
1 &= g'(q(x,y))\frac{\partial q(x,y)}{\partial y}\\
1 &= f'(q(x,y))\frac{\partial q(x,y)}{\partial x}
\end{align}
which means that both $f'(q(x,y))$ and $\frac{\partial q(x,y)}{\partial y}$ are not $0$. But
\begin{aligned}
x &= f(q(x,y))\\
\implies0 &= f'(q(x,y))\cdot\frac{\partial q(x,y)}{\partial y}
\end{aligned}
So there is a contradiction.

Comment: One systematic way to think about this kind of problem is by using the theory of transcendence degree / transcendence bases. You should be able to find what you need by searching for those terms on Google or your favorite commutative algebra reference.

Comment: A different approach might be showing that one doesn't satisfy the universal property of the other